# Recording using audioRecorder with initWithURL

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am struggling to update an existing project which now throws the error

> 'initWithURL:' is unavailable: not available on iOS

It is most strange as the project has worked fine on previous versions of Xcode (now using 5)

```
-(void)startRecording
{   

    //NSInteger currCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:AUDIO_FILENAME_COUNT];
    NSString *caldate =@"record";
    recorderFilePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp4", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, caldate] retain];

    CFStringRef fileString = (CFStringRef) recorderFilePath;
    CFURLRef fileURL =  CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL,fileString,kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,false);
    NSLog (@"Recorded file path: %@", fileURL); 

    if (fileURL) {
        soundFileURL = (NSURL *) fileURL;
        //CFRelease (fileURL);
    }

    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;

    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                             sizeof (doChangeDefaultRoute),
                             &doChangeDefaultRoute);

    //kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker

    if (audioRecorder)
    {
        [audioRecorder release];
        audioRecorder = nil;
    }

    audioRecorder = [[AudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: soundFileURL];

    [audioRecorder setNotificationDelegate: self];  // sets up the recorder object to receive property change notifications 
    AudioSessionSetActive(true);

    [audioRecorder record];

     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. It turned out to be forward class issue. Actually check if same line of code (errored one) is flagging out some other warning also. Mine was showing forward class warning. When i sort that out this error also got sorted.